# How to find missing rows in csv using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My CSV file looks something like this

```
location StartDate EndDate
Austin  10/24/20. 10/31/20
Austin  11/28/20. 12/05/20
Austin  12/26/20. 01/02/21
Austin  10/10/20  10/17/20
Austin  10/03/20. 10/10/20
Kansas  10/24/20. 10/31/20
Kansas  11/28/20. 12/05/20
Kansas  12/26/20. 01/02/21
Kansas  10/03/20. 10/10/20
Tampa   10/24/20. 10/31/20
Tampa   11/28/20. 12/05/20
Tampa   10/03/20. 10/10/20
```

As you can see Kansas is missing  10/10/20 - 10/17/20 and Tampa is missing 2 records for 10/10 and 12/26. Is there a way to find this missing records from the file using Pandas and python?

Comment: Perhaps calculate the time delta and if greater than a threshold, flag as missing.  What have you tried / researched so far?

Answer (score 4):

Let's try `pivot` and `unstack`:

```
(df.pivot(*df)
   .stack(dropna=False)
      .loc[lambda x: x.isna()]
)
```

Output:

```
location  StartDate 
Kansas    2020-10-10   NaT
Tampa     2020-10-10   NaT
          2020-12-26   NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: `df.pivot(*df)` is a nice trick but shouldn't we assume that sample dataframes are minimized for example, and production data would have different shape?

Comment: @RichieV I would strongly disagree, and expect a user to provide a representative enough sample of their data to be able to give an acceptable answer. Otherwise we get into a problem with a moving target where the sample keeps getting updated with edge cases

Comment: @G.Anderson I don't mean to make a big fuzz about this, I agree that it is the questioner's responsibility to clarify how the sample is expected to grow... but I've frequently seen answers being updated precisely because they didn't provide a generalized solution

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unstack` and `stack(dropna=False)`

```py
df = df.groupby(['StartDate', 'EndDate', 'location']).size().unstack()
df = df.stack(dropna=False).rename('count').reset_index()
missing = df[df['count'].isna()]
```

Output

```
print(missing)
    StartDate   EndDate location  count
4    10/10/20  10/17/20   Kansas    NaN
5    10/10/20  10/17/20    Tampa    NaN
14  12/26/20.  01/02/21    Tampa    NaN
```

Basically you are making a square matrix for all `StartDate` and all `location`. When you `unstack` pandas places a `NaN` if the combination of row/column labels is not in the dataframe. Then when you `stack` pandas drops those `NaN` by default, but you can pass `dropna` parameter to keep them precisely for this use case.